# How does `declare` in LLVM IR works

Tags: llvm

For example

```
@.str = private unnamed_addr constant [13 x i8] c"hello world\0A\00"

declare i32 @puts(i8* nocapture) nounwind

define i32 @main() {
  %cast210 = getelementptr [13 x i8], [13 x i8]* @.str, i64 0, i64 0

  call i32 @puts(i8* %cast210)
  ret i32 0
}
```

I don't understand where the function `puts` comes from. It seems to be a C function in `stdio.h`, but what does this have to do with LLVM? Where is its implementation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Speaking in C/C++ terms, each translation unit can reference external symbols. For compiler it doesn't matter where symbol is actually defined as far as you have a declaration for it.

After compiling your `.c` files you get something that needs to be linked together (object files `.o` or LLVM IR `.ll`/`.bc`). On the linking stage all symbol definitions are resolved (in different ways).

In your example, the `puts` function is usually located in the system `libc`, which gets linked automatically by default. You won't find LLVM IR code for this function unless you somehow compiled whole `libc` into LLVM IR.

Read some general tutorial on the "compilation and linking" topic.